# Use dataframes for Decision tree classifier in spark with string fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, decision-tree

I have managed to get my Decision Tree classifier work for the RDD-based API, but now I am trying to switch to the Dataframes-based API in Spark.

I have a dataset like this (but with many more fields) :

country, destination, duration, label

```
Belgium, France, 10, 0
Bosnia, USA, 120, 1
Germany, Spain, 30, 0
```

First I load my csv file in a dataframe :

```
val data = session.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("/home/Datasets/data/dataset.csv")
```

Then I transform string columns into numerical columns

```
val stringColumns = Array("country", "destination")

val index_transformers = stringColumns.map(
  cname => new StringIndexer()
    .setInputCol(cname)
    .setOutputCol(s"${cname}_index")
)
```

Then I assemble all my features into one single vector, using VectorAssembler, like this :

```
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
   .setInputCols(Array("country_index", "destination_index", "duration_index"))
   .setOutputCol("features")
```

I split my data into training and test :

```
val Array(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
```

Then I create my DecisionTree Classifier

```
val dt = new DecisionTreeClassifier()
  .setLabelCol("label")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
```

Then I use a pipeline to make all the transformations

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(index_transformers, assembler, dt))
```

I train my model and use it for predictions :

```
val model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)

val predictions = model.transform(testData)
```

But I get some mistakes I don't understand :

When I run my code like that, I have this error :

```
[error]  found   : Array[org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer]
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage
[error]           .setStages(Array(index_transformers, assembler,dt))
```

So what I did is that I added a pipeline right after the index_transformers val, and right before val assembler :

```
val index_pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(index_transformers)
val index_model = index_pipeline.fit(data)
val df_indexed = index_model.transform(data)
```

and I use as training set and testing set, my new df_indexed dataframe, and I removed index_transformers from my pipeline with assembler and dt

```
val Array(trainingData, testData) = df_indexed.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(assembler,dt))
```

And I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data type StringType is not supported.
```

It basically says I use VectorAssembler on String, whereas I told it to use it on df_indexed which has now a numerical column_index, but it doesn't seem to use it in vectorAssembler, and i just don't understand..

Thank you

**EDIT**

Now I have almost managed to get it work :

```
val data = session.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("/home/hvfd8529/Datasets/dataOINIS/dataset.csv")

val stringColumns = Array("country_index", "destination_index", "duration_index")

val stringColumns_index = stringColumns.map(c => s"${c}_index")

val index_transformers = stringColumns.map(
  cname => new StringIndexer()
    .setInputCol(cname)
    .setOutputCol(s"${cname}_index")
)

val assembler  = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(stringColumns_index)
    .setOutputCol("features")

val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("label")
  .setOutputCol("indexedLabel")

val Array(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))

// Train a DecisionTree model.
val dt = new DecisionTreeClassifier()
  .setLabelCol("indexedLabel")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setImpurity("entropy")
  .setMaxBins(1000)
  .setMaxDepth(15)

// Convert indexed labels back to original labels.
val labelConverter = new IndexToString()
  .setInputCol("prediction")
  .setOutputCol("predictedLabel")
  .setLabels(labelIndexer.labels())

val stages = index_transformers :+ assembler :+ labelIndexer :+ dt :+ labelConverter

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(stages)


// Train model. This also runs the indexers.
val model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)

// Make predictions.
val predictions = model.transform(testData)

// Select example rows to display.
predictions.select("predictedLabel", "label", "indexedFeatures").show(5)

// Select (prediction, true label) and compute test error.
val evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
  .setLabelCol("indexedLabel")
  .setPredictionCol("prediction")
  .setMetricName("accuracy")
val accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
println("accuracy = " + accuracy)

val treeModel = model.stages(2).asInstanceOf[DecisionTreeClassificationModel]
println("Learned classification tree model:\n" + treeModel.toDebugString)
```

except that now I have an error saying this :

```
value labels is not a member of org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer
```

and I don't understand, as I am following examples on spark doc :/

Comment: I think labelconverter should not have the parenthesis after labelIndexer.labels. Should be:val labelConverter = new IndexToString().setInputCol("prediction").setOutputCol("predictedLabel").setLabels(labelIndexer.labels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did for my first problem :

```
val stages = index_transformers :+ assembler :+ labelIndexer :+ rf :+ labelConverter

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(stages)
```

For my second issue with label, I needed to use .fit(data) like this

```
val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("label_fraude")
  .setOutputCol("indexedLabel")
  .fit(data)
```

Comment: In the first part, is that "rf" a typo for "dt"? In the second part, the "label_fraude" is inconsistent with your question. Can you please update your answer with your complete solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(index_transformers ++ Array(assembler, dt): Array[PipelineStage])
```

Comment: I still have the same error :(

And I have also tried   

val stages = index_transformers :+ assembler :+ dt

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
    .setStages(stages)

but not working : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data type StringType is not supported